# Ionic App freezes when focus out text box

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created app in ionic 3.App is working fine except when I click out side text box after entering some data then app gets freezes.Below is the code of html page.

```
 <label for="txtphoneInfo">Available Phone # <img alt="Required" src="../../assets/imgs/sp.gif" class="redBox" longdesc="Required" /></label>
                                <div class="textBoxValidate">
                                    <input type="tel" name="txtphoneInfo" value="" id="txtphoneInfo" pattern="\d*" maxlength="10" style="text-transform: uppercase;" data-warn_id="warntxtphone" (keypress)="isNumberKey($event)" />
                                    <span id="warntxtphone" class="requiredFld">Required</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I would suggest that you run your app with `ionic serve` command, and view it in the browser.
Then, in the browser, loop at the console messages you are getting. This should/could point you in the right direction.
Is your code waiting for something else? I see that it's labelled as `"requiredFld"`. Is some JS not firing correctly?

Comment: Hi @vr_driver, thanks for your response. I did run my app with ionic serve and nothing appear in console. also it is working fine in browser. I also run my app through ngrok in safari , and it works fine. After publish , this strange behavior of freezing appear

Comment: Are you running it in the Android environment?  If so, you can see other console messages with Chrome too.

Comment: I am running it for IOS .

Comment: Is your 'isNumberKey' triggering on MouseOut? Call me crazy, but can you append a "return false;" to the end of that function call?

Comment: let me add return false

Comment: that was the culprit.Thanks for help

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to help. :)